# Multivariate time series forecasting with the extended Theta method

Tags: forecasting

I am looking for an implementation (better if in Python) of the extended Theta method for multivariate time series forecasting, presented in the following paper:

D. Thomakos, K. Nikolopoulos, Forecasting Multivariate Time Series with the Theta Method, J. Forecast. 34, 220–229 (2015)

Any suggestion?

Comment: Without having fully read the paper, have you looked at the [`statsmodel` implementation](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/theta-model.html)? They refer to both the initial 2000 paper as well as the 2015 preprint with the improvements.

Comment: They refer to a 2015 paper that is *not* the one I indicated in my query. Indeed, the statsmodel implementation addresses the univariate case only.